# Identify these "Retro Machines"

Tags: character-identification

Who are all of the "Retro Machines" depicted on this shirt design, and what properties are they from?

[image: Retro Machines]

Comment: Shirt available [here](http://shirt.woot.com/offers/retro-machines?ref=eml_sh_dly_img&utm_source=Daily+Digest&utm_campaign=0e8842cec5-Daily+Digest+-+20160205+-+Shirt.Woot&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_c5ca76da11-0e8842cec5-282244626) - I have no affiliation with woot or the artist.

Comment: How could the artist have left out Robby?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm more concerned with the fact that they're not all machines in the first place.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do think an argument against Evangelions being machines could be made. Especially EVA01

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn: Well, [cyborgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelion_(mecha)) are by definition partially machines. :-) But I plead ignorance of Evangelions.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised at the fact they call BB8 a "retro" machine, despite being from a movie that came out only a few months ago.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs I assume that "retro" refers to the art style, rather than the machines themselves, since not all of them are actually retro as you said. C-3PO is old, but that particular version (with the red arm) is also from The Force Awakens.

Comment: To be retro it should have a Cylon. I love those old ones. "As you command"

Comment: Samus isn't a machine, she is a person.  Iron man too, come to think of it.

Comment: @nexus_2006 So is Metroid a robot, or does he have a gun on his arm?

Comment: As always, I miss Kryten.

Comment: @CBredlow Samus is a person in a suit.  This is a metroid => http://metroid.wikia.com/wiki/Metroid_%28species%29

Comment: clearly, this 3po is from the force awakens

Comment: "By your command" @ZanLynx

Comment: The choice of words here is clear - "machine", not robot. Iron Man's suit is a machine. So is, I presume, Samus Aran's. *Most* of the choices are robots, which might imply the rest are too, but that's not what it claims to be.

Comment: EVA-01 is not a machine, technically it is a suit/restraint mechanism. Oh man, why do I even know this... and what, no "Max" from Disney's "The Black Hole"

Answer (score 35):

#### First Row

1. C-3PO (*Star Wars*)
2. R2-D2 (*Star Wars*)
3. Iron Man
4. Optimus Prime (*Transformers*)

#### Second Row

1. Data (*Star Trek*)
2. Marvin the Paranoid Android (*Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*)
3. Bender (*Futurama*)
4. Sentinel (*X-Men*)

#### Third Row

1. EVA-01 (*Neon Genesis Evangelion*)
2. Gipsy Danger (*Pacific Rim*)
3. RX-78-2 (*Gundam*)
4. Cyberman (*Dr. Who*)

#### Fourth Row

1. T-800 (*Terminator*; [as confirmed by the artist](https://web.archive.org/web/20160211095736/http://shirt.woot.com/forums/viewpost.aspx?postid=6700030&pageindex=1#post6700743))
2. BB-8 (*Star Wars*)
3. Samus Aran (*Metroid*)
4. Megatron (*Transformers*)

Comment: @phantom42 do you think you could accept this cw answer?

Answer (score 22):

C3P0 (Star Wars) - R2D2 (Star Wars)- Iron Man (Marvel) - Optimus Prime  (Transformers)

Data (Star Trek) - Marvin (Hitchikers Guide) - Bender (Futurama) - Probably a Sentinel (X-men)

EVA 001 (Evangelion) - Gipsy Danger (Pacific Rim) - RX782 Gundam - Cyberman (Doctor Who)

Probably a Terminator - BB-8 (Star Wars) - Samus (Metroid) - Megatron (Transformers)

Comment: The 'Terminator' on the first spot in the fourth row might also be Brad Bird's [Iron Giant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129167/).

Comment: Iron giant is a popular guess but the head doesn't match very well and IG doesn't have the little dial thing on the right side

Comment: [From the artist, rasabi](http://shirt.woot.com/forums/viewpost.aspx?postid=6700743): The bottom was intended to be a T-800 Terminator.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that several of these are characters in suits (e.g. Iron Man). Even Gypsy Danger technically has people inside it.